# I have trouble getting current time using api

Tags: javascript, api

I am getting wheater prognose with my code. I want to get time as well.
How can I get time?

my code:

```
function Get() {
            var txtCity = document.getElementById("txtCity").value;
            var weather = new XMLHttpRequest();
            weather.open("GET", "http://api.wunderground.com/api/df3f2ab5e1db8f97/conditions/q/"+txtCity+".json", false);
            weather.send(null);
            var r = JSON.parse(weather.response);
            var dis = "Current location: " + r.current_observation.display_location.full + "<p>";
            dis += "current temp: " + r.current_observation.temperature_string + "<p>";
            dis += "current wind speed: " + r.current_observation.wind_string + "<p>";
            dis += "current time: " + r.current_observation.time_string;//returns undefined
            document.getElementById("weather").innerHTML = dis;  
        }
```

Comment: `weather.responseText`

Comment: I dont get it how you mean

Comment: `weather.response` is for typed responses, since you didn't specify a response type only responseText will be available.

Comment: I tried but didn't work

Comment: To the OP: Did you ever come back to this question? Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs: http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/conditions

time_string is not in the response, but observation_time is.

Replace this:

```
...
dis += "current time: " + r.current_observation.time_string;
...
```

With this:

```
...
dis += "current time: " + r.current_observation.observation_time;
...
```